# Glassfish cluster and http session replication

Tags: java, http, session, glassfish, cluster-computing

I am actually trying to configure and test http session replication on a glassfish server. I followed this [tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/shreedhar/entry/how_to_configure_and_test) but unfortunatly I am unable to make it work. (clusterjsp.war is the webap I use to test session replication)

I tried on both glassfish 3.1.2.2 and 4.1.1

According to the tutorial, here are the steps I am following :

- start-domain
- create-cluster c1
- create-local-instance --cluster c1 i1
- create-local-instance --cluster c1 i2
- deploy --availabilityenabled=true --target c1 clusterjsp.war

From there, I restart the domain and start the cluster. I can access at the webapp on each of the instances but I am expecting to have the same session on both instances, which is not the case. The session ID are different.

When checking my cluster config on the administrationc console of glassfish, I can see high availibility is enabled and Web Container availibility is enabled too and set on replicated.

Am I forgetting something on the configuration ?